# How to add placeholder to django admin 'search fields'?

Tags: html, django-admin

I feel **widgets** can solve the problem. But mostly it is for the model field. I am using django-suit as my admin and I specify a search field like:

```
search_fields = ['order__order_no']
```

In default, it appears a search box with placeholder 'Keyword'. I want to customize it. BUT not clear how to use widget in this scenario.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11411622/add-help-text-for-search-field-in-admin-py It appears there is no easy way to do this.