# How to add placeholder text to search box in Django Admin?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-admin

I have a bunch of instances of `ModelAdmin` defined in `admin.py` file and many of them use the `search_fields` parameter. However, they all don't use the same variables to search by, and so I'm wondering what might be the most Pythonic/easiest way to add some placeholder text to the `input` to make it clear to the system admins what they're searching by.

I'm using Django 1.10.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As of Django 4.0, you can use the `search_help_text` property of the `ModelAdmin`:

```
@admin.register(MyModel)
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  search_fields = ['my_field']
  search_help_text = "Your help text here"
```

Answer (score -1):

You can simply place a default value to the field by adding this attribute: default='[Placeholder goes here]'

Answer (score -2):

You need to override the `admin/search_form.html` template as described in this question:

[Add help_text for search field in admin.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11411622/add-help-text-for-search-field-in-admin-py)

Answer (score -2):

You can simply add the attribute `placeholder` to `input`

Example:

```
<input name="search" placeholder="Searching by name...">
```