# How to add placeholder text to a Django Admin field

Tags: python, django

I'd like to add placeholder text to a field in the Django Admin change form. In a regular ModelForm you can do this by overriding the field's widget or by modifying `self.fields['my_field'].widget` in the ModelForm `__init__()` method. How do I do something similar for a Django Admin?

Comment: have a look at this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11411622/add-help-text-for-search-field-in-admin-py

Comment: Thanks @AtlasBravoos, using JavaScript is certainly one option, though it's a little bit fragile

Answer (score 4):

The documented way is to override [`get_form()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_form):

> The base implementation uses `modelform_factory()` to subclass form,
>   modified by attributes such as **fields** and **exclude**.

If you look at the docs for [**modelform_factory**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/forms/models/#django.forms.models.modelform_factory) you'll see that you can pass `widgets` as **kwarg**. So this should work:

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        kwargs['widgets'] = {
            'name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'e.g. John Doe'})
        }
        return super().get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
```

or, if you want to be sure you're not overriding any widgets (if you're inheriting from a subclass of `ModelAdmin`):

```
 kwargs['widgets'] = kwargs.get('widgets', {})
 kwargs['widgets'].update({'name': ...})
```

Answer (score 1):

Override the `render_change_form()` method on your ModelAdmin, which provides access to the form instance:

```
class Address(model.Model):
    street = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class AddressAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def render_change_form(self, request, context, *args, **kwargs):
        form_instance = context['adminform'].form
        form_instance.fields['street'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = 'Your street'
        return super().render_change_form(request, context, *args, **kwargs)
```

This approach would be the same for other field attributes like  attributes like `autocomplete`, `autofocus`, `min`, `max`, `required`, `type` or `pattern`. You also have access to `context["original"]` which provides the model instance, in case you'd like to change the behavior based on the model instance.

The source code is the best reference for this:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/_modules/django/contrib/admin/options/#ModelAdmin

Comment: Where is `render_change_form` documented? It's not part of the methods documented [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/admin/) so it's not guaranteed to remain stable.

Comment: There's no reason to believe that `render_change_form` is in any way unstable. With `get_form` you're working with the form class, where in `render_change_form` you're working with the form instance. Access to the form instance allows you to to modify the widget, rather than having to replace it. It also provides access to the model instance in case you want to customise the form dynamically (which is very useful, but another story).

Comment: I meant unstable in the sense that any changes to its behaviour or signature (or even removal if the rendering logic is changed) won’t be mentioned in release notes of future django releases because it’s not part of the “official” ModelAdmin API.

Answer (score 1):

This is a way of doing it without having to manually add placeholder text to each field:

**`admin.py`**

```
from django import forms


class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def render_change_form(self, request, context, *args, **kwargs):
        form_instance = context['adminform'].form
        for key, field in form_instance.fields.items():
            if isinstance(field.widget, (forms.TextInput, forms.EmailInput)):
                field.widget.attrs.update({'placeholder': field.label})
        return super().render_change_form(request, context, *args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this is:

```
class MyModelAdmin(model.ModelAdmin):   
    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
     #--> Get form 
        form = super().get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
     #--> Add placeholder for field
        form.base_fields['the_field_name'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = "My_Place_Holder_Text"
     #--> Return form
        return form
    #---
#---
```

This is similar to the answer of dirkgroten. The advantage here is that there is no need to worry about the widget used for the field.