# How to add placeholder for search field in admin.py

Tags: python, django

How can I add placeholder in django for a search field I am using in admin.py with Django3.1 as:

```py
class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['community']
    search_fields = ['community']
```

Is there any way to do something like this?

```py
class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ['community']
    search_input_placeholder = 'Please input community id'
```

Comment: Maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53066989/14316282) is useful?

Comment: @RolvApneseth That is one solution, but seems not pythonic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Django 4, you can now add a `search_help_text`.

More details in the doc [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.search_help_text).